# Heroku and Yahoo! Apps

Tags: ruby, heroku, sinatra, yahoo

I have created an App on Heroku which works perfectly in a Web Browser. As a second step, I want to view the App hosted on Heroku in Yahoo! App.

Its pretty simple to open any webpage in a Yahoo! App. One just need to mention the URL where the site is LIVE and rest is taken care by Yahoo! App. However, if I try to open the App hosted Heroku in Yahoo! App, it fails with 404.

As a reference, one can try creating an app on Heroku which just takes a few minutes and try for yourself. You can also use [Sinatra MVC](http://sinatra-mvc.heroku.com/welcome/) if you want to use pre-built app on Heroku and see if this gets displayed. I have already posted the problem on Yahoo! Forum [here](http://developer.yahoo.net/forum/index.php?showtopic=4825).

In my personal opinion, the issue might be because of some internal redirection which Heroku is doing but I am not sure about it.

Please have a look and share your thoughts if possible.

Thanks in advance,

Muhammad Haseeb Khan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yahoo! has implemented a fix to this problem in their latest update.

[Release Notes](http://developer.yahoo.com/yap/releasenotes/) state the following:

**Proxy URL with redirects is not fetched by YAP**

Answer (score 0):

Well it's not because of internal redirection. It might be a DNS issue (In which case it may work if you try again).

If you could post the heroku url of your app (or another sample application that is experiencing the same issue) then I could probably tell you more.

Comment: George, Thanks for your reply.

Due to some NDA restrictions, I can't post the URL publicly, but you can try this URL: http://sinatra-mvc.heroku.com/ if possible.

Its important to note here that if I use other URLs which aren't hosted on Heroku, for instance, http://www.tkxel.com, it is displayed perfectly in the Yahoo! App Container.

Thanks in advance.

- Haseeb

Comment: Try adding the /welcome/ to the url for the Yahoo App if that's not there already. I see that there is also a script tag that references a js file that does not exist (http://stats.ffiirree.com/heroku.js). Maybe fixing that would help?

Edit: Actually, it looks like tags that reference external js or stylesheets are likely the problem. Check out this thread: http://developer.yahoo.net/forum/?showtopic=850&endsession=1

Comment: Thanks George. You are correct that the JS doesn't exist but even if you try a very simple Hello World App [Without any Javascript / CSS], even that doesn't gets rendered in the Yahoo! App container. This might be some other issue. I hope somenone from Yahoo!/Heroku replies soon.

Comment: I contacted with Heroku Support and they asked to check for the Host Headers Yahoo! Container is sending to Heroku. Is there a way to check that ?

Comment: It may be mentioned in the documentation. Only other way I can think of to check the headers would be to point the container to a web server that you can view the logs on and then see what those say.